# Find a height of a node in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree

In my JavaScript code, I am trying to find a height of a given node in a`Binary SearchTree.`
Here is my code

```
class BinarySearchTree2 {
    constructor() {
        this.root = null;
    }

    findHeight(node = this.root,nodeData,level = 1) {
        let root = node;
        if(root === null) 
            return null;
        if(root.data === nodeData) 
            return level;
        let foundLevel = 0;
        if(nodeData < root.data) {
            foundLevel = findHeight(root.left,nodeData,level + 1);
        }
        // If you have found it on the left subtree, that's it, return
        if(foundLevel !== 0) 
            return foundLevel;
        foundLevel = findHeight(root.left,nodeData,level + 1);
        return foundLevel;

    }
}
```

Now, when I insert some nodes and try to find a height of a node like :

```
let BST = new BinarySearchTree2();

BST.insert(8);
BST.insert(3);
BST.insert(10);
BST.insert(1);
BST.insert(6);
BST.insert(14);
BST.insert(4);
BST.insert(7);
BST.insert(13);

BST.findHeight(this.root,14,1);
```

It throws error. Saying `findHeight` is not defined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you may need to call `this.findHeight()` instead

Comment: Can you add the full class code? We need `insert` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call a method inside itself, you still need to use `this` since the method you are trying to call is actually attached to the object itself. So,

```
class BinarySearchTree2 {
    constructor() {
        this.root = null;
    }

    findHeight(node = this.root,nodeData,level = 1) {
        let root = node;
        if(root === null) 
            return null;
        if(root.data === nodeData) 
            return level;
        let foundLevel = 0;
        if(nodeData < root.data) {
            // change here
            foundLevel = this.findHeight(root.left,nodeData,level + 1);
        }
        // If you have found it on the left subtree, that's it, return
        if(foundLevel !== 0) 
            return foundLevel;
        // change here
        foundLevel = this.findHeight(root.left,nodeData,level + 1);
        return foundLevel;

    }
}
```

would work as expected

Answer (score 0):

This line should be

`findHeight(node = this.root,nodeData,level = 1) {`

Like this

```
findHeight = (node = this.root,nodeData,level = 1) => {
```

Or you need to bind your function to the clas in the constructor.